# Long waiting timeout for python extension enabling [Offline code server]

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed code server on an offline server and installed the python extension. When opening the python file, it takes about ~5 mins to wait it timeout for checking latest version of python extension. Is there configuration that can disable checking the latest version or change the timeout ?

I had performed the following action, but still in-vain

- Extensions: Auto Update: disable
- Update mode: none